# Limit feature availability (show or hide a button) when the due date has passed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a scenario in my app where I have to limit a functionality if the date has expired. For example, if I set the limit field "2016-11-20" the button "Add your Journal" will disappear or throwing an error when the time "2016-11-20" has passed. How to do it in Laravel 5.3 ? I'd like to use gate or policy if possible.

Edition table Migrations :

```
Schema::create('edition', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('volume');
            $table->text('cover')->nullable();
            $table->integer('number');
            $table->date('limit')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Button view :

```
@if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->level == 'author')
                                <div class="tombol-nav">
                                    <a href="../journal/create?edition={{$edition->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Add Your Journal</a>
                                </div>
                                @endif
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: pardon my English, not my native language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed use the `Gate` Facade. There's [documentions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#via-blade-templates) on how to use it with blade.

You can [create policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#creating-policies) and have something like this.

```
Gate::define('add-journal', function ($user, $edition) {
     $limit = $edition->limit 
     return (time() < $limit)
});
```

Then in your view, you can use blade

```
@can('add-journal', $edition)
    <div class="tombol-nav">
        <a href="../journal/create?edition={{$edition->id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Add Your Journal</a>
    </div>
@endcan
```

As a side note, for your `Auth::check()`, I suggest you put that in a separate middleware.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but the url "../journal/create?edition={{$edition->id}}" is still accessible (the button disappear) even though the time has passed. In this case do I have to create middleware to handle it so the route is no longer accessible as well ?

Comment: Indeed. You have to create a middleware to protect your route using `Gate::allows()`

Comment: or use policies and use authorize helper (in controller) google around.